# How to create a new list inside foreach in scala

Tags: scala

I am newbie to scala and just trying out stuff, below is what I am trying

```
scala> var col  = List[String]()
col: List[String] = List()

scala> List("a", "b", "c").foreach(x => x :: col)

scala> println(col)
List()
```

Actually, I was expecting col to contain a,b,c, what am I missing?

Comment: Prepending elements to a list does not modify the list.

Comment: I see, so how do I modify the list in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need an assignment in the `foreach`

```
scala> var col  = List[String]()
col: List[String] = List()

scala> List("a", "b", "c").foreach(x => {col = x :: col})

scala> col
res0: List[String] = List(c, b, a)
```

The operation `x :: col` simply returns a new list consisting of the element `x` prepended to `col`, the original `col` is not changed. You would need to reassign `col` to this newly generated list.

Note however that this would not typically be considered idiomatic Scala since you are using side-effects.

Comment: Thanks @evan058, now that empty list in my example make sense to me!

Comment: @samadhi000 No problem. Just as an FYI, [upvotes are the currency of thanks on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You can upvote multiple answers which you find useful (but you can only accept one, which you did for my post).

Comment: I would like to but looks like I don't have even privilege

Comment: Ooh, my bad. I didn't think that applied to your own questions.

Answer (score 6):

The `::` method on list does not add anything to the list, it creates a new list with the value prepended to it, you are discarding this new list instead of reassigning it to `col`.  `x => col = x :: col` will add each element of your list to `col`. Note that `col` will then be List("c","b","a"), the order is reversed because you are pre-pending the elements to `col`.

Note that `foreach` returns nothing and is designed for side-effecting operations.  If you simply want to transform a collection or load elements into another collection there are better methods to use.

For your specific operation, the most appropriate method is `foldRight` which iterates elements in reverse order, right-to-left.  We want to iterate in reverse here because when you prepend elements to a list one at a time the order gets reversed.

`val col = List("a", "b", "c").foldRight(List[String]())((x, acc) => x :: acc)` will produce a `List("a", "b", "c")`.  This has the advantage that we no longer need to use `var` to declare a mutable variable, and in fact we don'
to need to declare our list ahead of time at all.

note, we could have used some special syntax to save some typing

`val col = List("a", "b", "c").foldRight(List[String]())(_ :: _)`

The underscores give us a shorter syntax to write function literals, I'll leave up to you to decide if it's more clear or not.

Comment: Thanks @puhlen for detailed explanation!

Comment: I would really like to up vote, but unfortunately I don't have an option to do so